# Processing Android Mode- error after every line

Tags: android, function, processing

so i have been using processing for quite a while and i am currently really into the android mode. 
i have got the newest version of processing and the sdk's installed, and i am also able to run my code on the phone.

One thing that really bothers me is that after every single line the error checker tells me things like "the function size(int,int); doesnt exist".

its not that much of a big deal since my code still compiles and i can run it, but its kind of going on my nerves.

btw there was a discussion considering that once, but no one seemed to have a solution.

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could use Android Studio to code Processing in Android, then you wont have this issues plus you get autocomplete and a lot more. I made a project mixing Processing and Android in Android studio here: https://github.com/josemg08/ProcessingFragment

Hope I've been of some help, Regard Jose